# Counting the number of times a phrase appears in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project at work and am very unfamiliar with excel vba. My boss has given me a worksheet with a column containing multiple student ID numbers and the rest of the columns are their answers to a survey. The survey was multiple choice and select all that apply.

I need to figure out a way to find the number of times one of the questions from the multiple choice questions were chosen. 
So for example if there are 10 students and there is a question with 2 answers and 5 people chose Yes and 5 chose No, I need it to ultimately tell me that 50% chose answer Yes and 50% chose answer No.

For the non multiple choice questions such as select all of the AP classes you have taken in the past, I need to know the same thing. Because this is a question, some of the cells in that column are blank.

I have been trying hard to find out a solution. So far I have tried to do a countIF on the number of times one of the answers appeared in a certain column (I cant search the whole worksheet because many of the questions have the same option of answers). My big problem with this is that I can't figure out how to write the range for the countif because I need the range to be the column number I declare it but the row needs to be the last row in the column with data. The range will not be the same every time because the amount of students who take the survey changes every time, so I woud need the range to be the first row of the column that I set it as, like A1 and then the last row in that column.

Any help or resources on how to do this would be great, I have been searching all over the internet and reading about vba.

Comment: if you have the list of questions, and you have preferred answers, you can set-up without VBA an overview sheet in Excel that has the question (verbatim from the quiz).  You then sumifs (allows multiple criteria, so verify the question is the same as your reference, then the answers that are Yes is the second criteria) and divide by countif (based on the question).  The ranges don't need to be defined using rows, this way, as they can be all of column A or B, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to recommend staying away from excel VBA and just using basic excel formulas to derive those answers. Is there any reason you feel the need for excel VBA here?

Anyhow, here is the standard way to define your range as the column + the last row. This example is for column A

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I was able to figure out how to get the last row, I dont know how to use the last row variable to write the range though.                                                                                                    And The main reason I went with VBA was because my boss suggested it and because there are over 100 columns and 600 rows. If you think it would be easier to just create a new worksheet and use the regular excel functions ill try that.

Comment: I see. Unless there are over 100 or 600 individual questions, I would still recommend going with what Cyril posted above me - using sumifs, or just other excel formulas to get your answers. It won't matter how many students are involved once you have the correct formula in place, it'll just change the range you're evaluating a tiny bit.

Comment: I started using the regular excel functions like you all suggested and it is definitely working better than the VBA. Thanks for yalls help!